# Ghost devices in adb devices

Tags: android, adb, platform-tools

Some extra devices are appearing in my adb devices list:

[image]

I do not have any android emulators running. I have tried:

1. restarting computer
2. Removing and reinstalling adb (as well as complete android sdk)

"adb kill-server" works as a work-around. But these devices re-appear after some time.
I have the latest android platform tools installed (version 23.1). May be it is a bug in this version.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check `devmgmt.msc` and see what is listed under the ADB Devices category? Do these appear all the time? Or only when your physical device is also plugged in?

Comment: There is no "ADB Devices" category, but "Android Device" and it only contains my physical device (no ghost device). This section only appears if I connect the device, otherwise it disappears. I see the ghost devices regardless of my device being connected.

Comment: Oops, I don't actually have my device plugged in so I was going by memory. In that category, does only one device appear? Or all three? In the output of `adb devices`, do the virtual devices still appear when your physical device is not plugged in?

Comment: Which ADB driver are you using? One from the phone manufacturer? Or the google-usb driver?

Comment: Virtual devices appear all the time. I am using google-usb driver.

Comment: Additionally, I was using Visual Studio Android Emulator. I had uninstalled that one as well, no luck.

Comment: @MattClark, all your questions are irrelevant. Emulators do not use USB drivers to communicate with the host and do not appear in the Device Manager.

Comment: @ParveenKumar, what is your actual problem with the ghost devices? As in what stops you from just ignoring them?

Comment: I use adb from command line as well as implicitly from Android gradle tasks e.g. Installing the app on a connected device. If there are multiple devices, it will fail. There are other scripts that I use adb to communicate to the device.  Plus it is annoying to have ghost devices :/

Comment: set system-wide environment variable `ANDROID_SERIAL` to the serial  number of your device and `adb` commands would use that

Comment: Thanks! It helps. However I do use multiple devices, but I guess I could write a script to set this variable. (`adb -d ...` also helps if using adb from command line)