# Ghost id in adb list

Tags: android, adb, platform-tools, debian-buster

I am experiencing an issue where my phone ( an actually physical device) has become a ghost device in adb. even when not connect I receive:

`adb devices
List of devices attached
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    no permissions`

I have run `kill-server` as well as rebooted several times (for other reasons). The real problem with this is that I can no longer connect my device to adb ( except by wireless-adb which is a pain.

I found this post [Ghost devices in adb devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497968/ghost-devices-in-adb-devices) in which a terrible workaround in accepted, and its for windows plus my problem is that my physical device is the ghost id not an emulator.

Update just tried `adb disconnect xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
and got no such device error

Comment: did you grant access from your phone?

Comment: yes, I frequently use my phone for 'real world' app testing

Answer (score 0):

Found this http://www.janosgyerik.com/adding-udev-rules-for-usb-debugging-android-devices/

somehow my udev rules had changed